# Google Plus Pages For Business / Blog

Tags: google, social-media

I've had several Google+ Pages for a few years now but never really used them, so I decided to delete the ones I had, and set up 2 new ones that will go with my new blogs, to also allow me to set up a related Youtube channel for each.

Problem is, it would seem that Google has once again changed it's entire layout, and way of doing things.

Now, I'm told you have to do it through "Google Business", which is fair enough, but once on there, there is no real direct link to set up a page related to your account. I've typed in the direct URL and you can pick it up that way, but is there another "official" method to follow to set up a page once on Google Business?

I'm curious about this because there is a clear way to "Restore" my deleted pages, but none to set up a new one, so I was wondering if this is Google's way of saying, "it's not worth setting up a new page because we're not going to be hosting them for much longer"?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the new listings you'd like to make are new businesses (and therefore not the same as the original 2 blogs). I'm also going to take a guess and assume that since this is for a blog, that you do not have a brick and mortar location for your service. Google My Business is used not only to make G+ profiles, but also to validate a physical location on Google Maps. They do not allow for non-physical locations to hold those kinds of listings:

https://support.google.com/business/answer/3038177?hl=en

However, you can use the following link to set up a Google+ profile (not technically a GMB listing) for a brand:

https://business.google.com/create

If I'm wrong and you do have a physical location, and meet the other requirements for a GMB listing, you should be able to claim your listing through there as well. If I was also incorrect in assuming that your new listing is for a new business (that is, you're working with the same businesses but want to set up new listings for some reason), I would strongly advise against that since you'll end up with duplicate listings that will cause competition with each other, and cause you some big, long lasting headaches.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. My blog isn't really a business, but I would obviously like a page to go with it. Originally, with Google+, you could just set up a Page linked to your main account, but this Google Business is completely different. I've "Restored" my original pages back to the Business Account I set up for my E-Mail, and it's now saying that I can add more pages to this account, so things should run as normal from now on. I just wish social media would stop changing every time we're just getting used to it!!!